# maths - percentage questions increase figures to reach percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I'm using SQL server to try an calculate this although to be fair the question is more maths/logic based.

I need to work out how to get a call received/answered ratio of a certain percentage, e.g. 80%

So if it currently stands at `12/6 - 50%`, I need to work out how many calls need to come in without any being dropped to get 80%,
the only way I can work out is by trial and error,

i.e.

```
13/7 = 54%
16/10= 63%
24/18= 75%
30/24= 80%
```

The only way I can think to do this at current is to add 1 to a variable each time until the percentage reaches 80 but its been a while since school, I'm sure there's a better way.

thanks

Comment: I should add is SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

If the current percentage, **cp** is

cp = a / b

and you ask how much to add to **a** to get percentage **p** then this is just a basic math and tells me

( a + x) / b = p

cp + x / b = p

x = b( p - cp)

example:

current 7/13 = 0.5385 = cp

desired 4/5 = 0.8

add 13*( 0.8 - 0.5385)= 3.4 = x to 7 to get 10.4/13=0.8

Comment: hi, this isnt quite my question either as if b increases so too will a, this only tells me what to add to a to get the percent doesnt it?

Comment: yes, it tells you what number add to a to get required percentage p

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple:

```
current = a / b
target (pt) = (a + x) / (b + x)
pt(b + x) = a + x
pt b + pt x = a + x
pt b - a = x - pt x = x(1 - pt)

x = (pt b - a) / (1 - pt)
```

So long as your target percentage is expressed as a decimal (`0.8`) rather than a percentage (`80`), this will work:

```
DECLARE @TotalCalls float;
DECLARE @CallsNotDropped float;
DECLARE @PercentageToReach float;
DECLARE @Result float;

SET @TotalCalls = 13;
SET @CallsNotDropped = 7;
SET @PercentageToReach = 0.8; -- 80%

SET @Result = ((@PercentageToReach * @TotalCalls) - @CallsNotDropped) 
              / (1 - @PercentageToReach);

SELECT
    @Result As 'Number to add/subtract',
    @TotalCalls + @Result As 'New total',
    @CallsNotDropped + @Result As 'New not dropped',
    100 * ((@CallsNotDropped + @Result) / (@TotalCalls + @Result)) As 'New %'
;

/*
 Output:

 | Number to add/subtract | New total | New not dropped | New % |
 | 17                     | 30        | 24              | 80    |
*/
```

Comment: haha, we have different opinions on simple :P but this is perefect. cheers

Answer (score -1):

Here is the formula: You can do this in straight SQL; no need for stored proc:

```
NewCallsNeeded = (TargetRatio * TotalCalls - DroppedCalls) / (1 - TargetRatio)
```

Comment: So basically, the same formula that I posted 55 minutes earlier, but with "calls not dropped" replaced with "dropped calls" because you didn't read the question properly? >:(

Comment: Down-voting my answer doesn't change the fact that you didn't read the question properly, didn't manage to copy the answer properly, and failed to include any sort of explanation of the answer. >:(